# Javascript: let user upload a file and send it to an email

Tags: javascript, file, email, upload

does anyobody know if this is possible to do in java script ? that I have a form for people to upload a photo with description but as opposed to uploading it a server, send it to an email address?

has anyone done this before?

Comment: I was thinking using the client's side mail service, like in unix!

Answer (score 1):

I know you mentioned sending an email directly from JavaScript, but unless I am mistaken, this is simply not possible.  There needs to be some kind of server technology in the backend to receive the file, then send it through some kind of mail server.  This is entirely possible in a way that is transparent to the user, but you would need to specify more on the type of server technology and platform to better be able to answer the question.

UPDATE:
sending the email would be done from the server-side, therefore the client needn't even receive credentials encrypted or not. I don't have experience with the Gmail API specifically, but I can only imagine google would provide a secure connection with which to send the email.

Comment: yeah thats what I thought too, lets say we use a gmail api to use a gmail account to send email to another email, could we encrypt the credential of that gmail account so that user wont have access to it ? or is there an online site we could use to send email

Comment: I dont mean like using the user's own gmail account, let say I have made a gmail account just to send photos to my own gmail account, when users upload it (I dont want users to login to anything)